# no permission to write in /mnt/extsd

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard, permission-denied

i'm unable to write into the external sd ( /mnt/extsd ) in mini x plus h24

i have already insert in the manifest

The system has two sd card, the first one is reachable with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() but the second is only reachable with absolute path

```
try{
        File file3 = new File("/mnt/extsd/", "file.txt");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file3));
        writer.write("hello");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exception return me this message
/mnt/extsd/file.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permissio denied)

Any suggestions?

Comment: i have already insert in the manifest 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

The system has two sd card, the first one is reachable with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() but the second is only reachable with absolute path

Answer (score 3):

add below permission in android manifest file.

**Write Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Read Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

EDIT

If you have already added that permission and still getting permission denied error, you might be writing to a read only directory or you're not allowed to write on the root of that directory.

You may want to check if the directory is writeable. Somthing like:

```
file3.canWrite()
```

or you may try adding a child directory, before writing

```
File newDir = new File("/mnt/extsd/myFiles");
newDir.mkdirs();
File file3 = new File(newDir.getAbsolutePath(), "file.txt");
```

Comment: always use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for getting SD-CARD path instead of hard-coded string

Comment: Hi, i have already add that permission. The problem is in the second sd. The system has two sd cards. The first is used by the os and the second must contains all my files and i can't write in it.

Comment: yes, i still get the error. Because the problem is in the second sd of my device. In the first sd i haven't problem to write and read file.

Comment: Hi I have edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, i create a subdirectory but unfortunately the application don't write the file.
The error is the same.

Comment: Have you checked if that directory is read only?

Answer (score 1):

Simple just add the permission in android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have already added the permissions in the manifest file then, 
try with these:

```
1) File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "file.txt");

2) File file2 = new File("file:///mnt/extsd/", "file.txt");

3) File file3 = new File("file:///mnt/sdcard/", "file.txt");
```

and then use

```
String filepath = "file:///" + file1.getAbsolutePath();
```